# ScrollBar на андроиде.

Tags: touch-webkit, gwt, android, java

Вопрос такой: возможно ли заставить работать скроллинг на андроиде?

Как я понял из доки, андроид может прокручивать только саму страницу, а если на станице есть панели использующие ScrollBar, то андроид игнорирует элементы скроллера.

Как пофиксить данный изъян?

Answer (score 3):

Скроллинг прекрасно работает в андроиде из коробки, не надо ничего заставлять, просто нужно читать документацию и грамотно использовать фреймворк.
Можно организовать прокрутку любого фрагмента активити, написав нужную разметку.
Прокрутка всего содержимого активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView ... >
    <LinearLayout ... >
        <TextView ... />
        <EditText ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Прокрутка части активити, за исключение первого EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout ... >
    <EditText ... />
    <ScrollView ... >
        <LinearLayout ... >
            <TextView ... />
            <EditText ... />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Внутри ScrollView должен быть только один дочерний элемент, поэтому чаще всего это один из лэйаутов, содержащий остальные виджеты.

Некоторые виджеты сами обеспечивают прокрутку, без использования ScrollView - ListView, Gallery, может еще какие-то, не помню точно.

[Документация по ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: Здесь спрашивается о другом. У автора есть приложение на GWT (открывается в браузере), а проблема в html-скроллере.

Answer (score 1):

Не видел такой проблемы в GWT. Насколько юзал SDK, там в xml просто атрибут скроллинга выставляется, хотя, может, я и не прав.